# Is it possible to get an out of state "failure to appear" for a felony case dismissed,if you are homeless?

Tags: criminal-law, rules-of-court, extradition

I just need a little more time to make enough money to travel, I can't get a job with a pending felony and don't have family to just give me money, I literally am scrapping to make it out there even if I have to drive alone with my child who is under 2 years as I have no one to watch her (I'm sure she'll end up in foster care). I am not purposely avoiding court, I have been dealing with this for two years and just this once I was unable to make it. Is the judiciary system really this cold hearted? Please help I have no one to turn to and could be facing jail time over circumstances I cant control.

Comment: Are you saying that you've been ordered to appear in a remote location within your state and you have no means to get there?

Comment: @user6726 The court case is out-of-state as stated in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Contact the public defender's office in the place where the court is located and explain your situation. If a public defender hasn't been appointed for you yet in the case, one will be when you appear, so they should be helpful.

If all else fails you may want to send a letter to the judge explaining your situation before you miss the hearing, requesting that the hearing be continued (which simply means rescheduled to a later date) until you are able to appear.